# How to pass state object/data to an (async) ajax callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing ajax call in a loop scope, and I need the success callback to use the correct "i" in which it was called.

like so (Pseudo JavaScript code):

```
for (i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; ++i)
{
   $.ajax( { ....,
         success : function(data) {
             // I want to use the correct i HERE
         }
   });
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work since by the time the success callback is called, the i value is out of sync with the callback...

Comment: You can set the async parameter of your ajax call to false.

Comment: @MikeHometchko please NO!

Comment: @A.Wolff well you shouldn't in most cases but it WILL work...I wasn't aware of the method that the answers below are showing...cool beans

Comment: @MikeHometchko ya but it's just the worst fix

Comment: @A.Wolff it has its uses, albeit quite rare.

Comment: I'm aware that calling it with "async : false" would solve the sync issue with "i", but it would not meet my requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The canonical solution to this is to use an immediately executed function expression to create a closure.

```
for (i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; ++i)
{
   (function (i) {
       $.ajax({
           success : function(data) {
               // I want to use the correct i HERE
           }
       });
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just create a function scope in place:

```
for (i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; ++i) {
    (function(i) {
        $.ajax({
             success : function(data) {
                console.log( i );
                 // I want to use the correct i HERE
             }
        });
    }(i));
}
```

Comment: I got 2 answers here :) and I love the solution